# Read last n bytes of file using Java

Tags: java, windows, file-processing

I have a crawler program which logs some files. Sometimes on the server, some error happens and the crawler creates massive log files which are somehow impossible to parse. For that reason, I wanted to create a simple program which reads about 1000 characters at the end of the log file and shows the messages to me (even if the crawler is still writing to that file). This will help me solve the problem without closing the crawler.

Comment: And the question is? What have you tried?

Comment: `tail /your/file` if you're on Linux/Unix.

Comment: @LukasKnuth: +1. Should have mentioned -f for +2... ;-)

Comment: @Axel `-f` would have also followed. He said that the file might be written to while he wants to fetch the last few lines.

Comment: Yes, I think that's quite handy. Normally I do something like `tail -f /your/file | grep error_of_interest`

Comment: BTW there was a windows tag added to the question, so no tail in default install...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29), then [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) your bytes out.

```
File file = new File("DemoRandomAccessFile.out");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

// Seek to the end of file
raf.seek(file.length() - n);
// Read it out.
raf.read(yourbyteArray, 0, n);
```

Comment: This is more relevant to my question, so I choose this as the answer. But I'm going with [Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) ;)

Comment: shouldn't use "rw" only "r", because the write mode in most windows environment will put a lock to file and the logger will not able to write the logs, that's why I told to open in read mode

Comment: If it's important to read all of the bytes, remember that the read method is not guaranteed to read more than one byte. Consider using `raf.readFully(yourbyteArray)` to make sure that you're reading all of the bytes that make up the length of the buffer that is being read into.

Answer (score 3):

There is a handy command line tool for this already on your computer. `tail -c 1000` would do what you are asking for. `tail -n 10` printing out the last 10 lines may be even more useful.

Comment: I'm on Windows. Is it available for Windows?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. [Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check the file length, lets say 1Mb

Open **for read** with [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Seek to position to  1024*1024-1000

read 1000 bytes

upvote :)

Comment: Since the [Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) does what I want, I don't need this, but this is exactly the way to go, hence the upvode ;)